# Can i react to change within a nested state only in Angular NGRX

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have a state testPortfolio and positions state within it. When I subscribe on testPortfolio it works fine and reacts on every change in it. But I want to subscribe only on positions and react on changes within this nested state but nothing seems to work for me?

```
this.store.select('testPortfolio').subscribe(testPortfolio=> {
  console.log(testPortfolio);
}); //works fine

this.store.select('testPortfolio', 'positions').subscribe(pos => {
  console.log(pos);
}); //only reacts ones onInit but doesn't react on changes
```

Answer (score 1):

Please add you subscription code inside `ngOnChanges` in you component class

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
   this.store.select('testPortfolio', 'positions').subscribe(pos => {
    console.log(pos);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ngrx has lifecyfle method in effects [ngrx doc](https://ngrx.io/guide/effects/lifecycle)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `distinctUntilChanged`, as described below.

```
this.store.select('testPortfolio')
.pipe(distinctUntilChanged((prev, curr) => prev.positions === curr.positions))
.subscribe(testPortfolio=> {
  console.log(testPortfolio);
});
```